# External URL post redirect without intermediate page (white page) in Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment, redirect

- Is there any possibility from the shop-system to perform a post redirection while clicking on the 'Place Order' button? We have tried posting the form data using the function **getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl** and there is an intermediate page (a blank page). Is it possible to eliminate such a page and perform a redirection (to the third-party site) while posting the values from the shop?

As an additional info, in the function **getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl**, we are using the *internal controller URL with custom block* like what have been followed with the PayPal Standard Payment.